# Loss in Keras Model evaluation

Tags: machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I am doing binary classification with Keras
`loss='binary_crossentropy'`, `optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam` and final layer is `keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)`.

As I know, `loss` value is used to evaluate the model during training phase. However, when I use `Keras` model evaluation for my **testing dataset** (e.g. `m_recall.evaluate(testData,testLabel)`, there are also `loss` values, accompanied by `accuracy` values like the output below

```
test size:  (1889, 18525)
1889/1889 [==============================] - 1s 345us/step
m_acc:  [0.5690245978371045, 0.9523557437797776]
1889/1889 [==============================] - 1s 352us/step
m_recall:  [0.24519687695911097, 0.9359449444150344]
1889/1889 [==============================] - 1s 350us/step
m_f1:  [0.502442331737344, 0.9216516675489677]
1889/1889 [==============================] - 1s 360us/step
metric name:  ['loss', 'acc']
```

What is the meaning/usage of `loss` during testing? Why it is so high (e.g. `0.5690` in `m_acc`)? The accuracy evaluation seems fine to me (e.g. `0.9523` in `m_acc`) but I am concerned about the `loss` too, does it make my model perform badly?

**P.S.** 
`m_acc`, `m_recall`, etc. are just the way I name my models (they were trained by on different metrics in `GridSearchCV`)

**Update:**
I just realized that `loss` values are not in percentage, so how are they calculated? And with current values, are they good enough or do I need to optimize them more?

Suggestions for further reading are appreciated too!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When defining a machine learning model, we want a way to measure the performance of our model so that we could compare it with other models to choose the best one and also make sure that it is good enough. Therefore, we define some **metrics** like accuracy (in the context of classification), which is the proportion of correctly classified samples by the model, to measure how our model performs and whether it is good enough for our task or not.

Although these metrics are truly comprehensible by us, however the problem is that they cannot be directly used by the learning process of our models to tune the parameters of the model. Instead, we define other measures, which are usually called **loss functions** or **objective functions**, which can be directly used by the training process (i.e. optimization). These functions are usually defined such that we expect that when their values are low we would have a high accuracy. That's why you would commonly see that the machine learning algorithms are trying to minimize a loss function with the expectation that the accuracy increases. In other words, the models are **indirectly learning** by optimizing the loss functions. The loss values are important during training of the model, e.g. if they are not decreasing or fluctuating then this means there is a problem somewhere that needs to be fixed.

As a result, what we are ultimately (i.e. when testing a model) concerned about is the value of metrics (like accuracy) we have initially defined and we don't care about the final value of loss functions. That's why you don't hear things like "the **loss value** of a [specific model] on the ImageNet dataset is 8.732"! That does not tell you anything whether the model is great, good, bad or terrible. Rather, you would hear that "this model performs with 87% **accuracy** on the ImageNet dataset".

Comment: Before marking this as an answer, could you please clarify why in testing `Keras` still output `loss`. As you said it is completely unnecessary. Also I would like to understand about those loss values. If they are not percentage then I find it difficult to comprehend how big or small they are. Or I just do not have to care about them at all?

Comment: @Long Note that we can still compare the values of the same loss functions for the same tasks (although in a restricted manner). And someone might be interested to know what the loss value is on the test dataset. So that does not make it completely unnecessary. But if your aim is to compare the performance of the models, you would mostly rely on the value of metrics and not the loss functions. Further, it is not easy or even sensible to compare the values of different loss functions. For example, it does not make sense to compare the value of mean squared error with binary cross entropy.

Comment: @Long They are different functions with different output range. As I said, in testing phase you should be more concerned about the metrics values (like accuracy). And in training phase you should only monitor **the trend** of values of loss function (i.e. whether it is decreasing, fixed, or increasing)  while having an eye on the values of metrics as well.