# Keras multi-label image classification with F1-score

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification, multilabel-classification

I am working on a `multi-label` image classification problem with the evaluation being conducted in terms of `F1-score` between system predicted and ground truth labels.

Given that, should I use `loss="binary_crossentropy"` or `loss=keras_metrics.f1_score()` where `keras_metrics.f1_score()` is taken from here: `https://pypi.org/project/keras-metrics/`? I am a bit confused because all of the tutorials I have found on the Internet regarding `multi-label` classification are based on the `binary_crossentropy` loss function, but here I have to optimize against `F1-score`.

Furthermore, should I set `metrics=["accuracy"]` or maybe `metrics=[keras_metrics.f1_score()]` or I should left this completely empty?

Comment: You should use `f1_score` as the metric value, not loss function. There is a difference between **loss function**, which is used in training of the model to guide the optimization process, and the (human interpretable) **metrics** which are used by us to understand the performance (i.e. accuracy) of the model. And one more important point is that the loss functions usually should be differentiable, which is not the case for most of metric functions used. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53497601/2099607) might be helpful as well.

Comment: So, just to confirm: I can use the `f1_score` from `keras_metrics` package as `metrics=` (human `interpretable`) but for `loss=` I should use a `differentiable` function. So, what about the following `differentiable` version of `F1-score`? `https://www.kaggle.com/rejpalcz/best-loss-function-for-f1-score-metric`

Comment: I can't verify that loss function now, but if it is 1) differentiable and 2) minimizing it implies a model with higher accuracy (i.e. higher metric value), then all is OK and you can use it. Another point: it's true that using the metric `'accuracy'` in Keras for a **multi-label** classification problem might give you a false signal, especially when the number of unique labels is high, since it gives very high values and therefore you might think that your model is doing **extremely** well which might not actually be the case. That's why `f1_score` is a much better metric to use.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will work toward these guidelines. And yes, the number of unique labels in my case is something like `3000` (after performing some cleaning - originally, there were about `5000` labels), so I guess 'accuracy' is not the right `loss` function to be used here so I should definitely use `f1_score`.

Comment: "so I guess 'accuracy' is not the right **loss** function to be used here so I should definitely use f1_score.": yeah, but I guess you mean the right **metric** function ;)

Comment: You are right. Sorry for the typo. I will re-express my last sentence for the sake of completion (and feel free to confirm this): 'accuracy' is not the right `metric` function to be used here. Instead, I **could** use `f1_score` from `keras_metrics` package. Then, I **must** find / implement a differentiale version of the `1 - F1-score` and use it as `loss` function (note that `loss` function should always get **minimized**).

Comment: That's almost correct with the only exception of this: "I **must** find / implement a differentiable version of the '1 - F1-score' and use it as loss function". Actually, there is no **necessity** for doing that because it might be the case that `binary_crossentropy` also works. However, if you can find a loss function which **directly** targets f1-score somehow and in your experiments it performs better than `binary_crossentropy` then all is good, you can use that instead. But I suggest you to first start experimenting with the most readily available option: `binary_crossentropy`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [user706838](https://stackoverflow.com/users/706838/user706838) answer ...

use the f1_score in https://www.kaggle.com/rejpalcz/best-loss-function-for-f1-score-metric

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K

def f1_loss(y_true, y_pred):

    tp = K.sum(K.cast(y_true*y_pred, 'float'), axis=0)
    tn = K.sum(K.cast((1-y_true)*(1-y_pred), 'float'), axis=0)
    fp = K.sum(K.cast((1-y_true)*y_pred, 'float'), axis=0)
    fn = K.sum(K.cast(y_true*(1-y_pred), 'float'), axis=0)

    p = tp / (tp + fp + K.epsilon())
    r = tp / (tp + fn + K.epsilon())

    f1 = 2*p*r / (p+r+K.epsilon())
    f1 = tf.where(tf.is_nan(f1), tf.zeros_like(f1), f1)
    return 1 - K.mean(f1)
```