# Why would I choose a loss-function differing from my metrics?

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, keras, gradient-descent, loss-function

When I look through tutorials in the internet or at models posted here at SO, I often see that the loss function differs from the metrics used to evaluate the model. This might look like:

`model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adadelta', metrics=['mae', 'mape'])`

Anyhow, following this example, why wouldn't I optimize `'mae'` or `'mape'` as loss instead of `'mse'` when I don't even care about `'mse'` in my metrics (hypothetically speaking when this would be my model)?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53497601/2099607) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many cases the metric you are interested might not be differentiable, so you cannot use it as a loss, this is the case for accuracy for example, where the cross entropy loss is used instead as it is differentiable.

For metrics that are already differentiable, you just want to get additional information from the learning process, as each metrics measures something different. For example the MSE has a scale that is squared from the scale of the data/predictions, so to get the same scale you have to use RMSE or the MAE. The MAPE gives you relative (not absolute) error, so all of these metrics measure something different that might be of interest.

In the case of accuracy, this metric is used because it is easily interpretable by a human, while cross entropy loss are less intuitive to interpret.

Comment: Arguing with being differentiable helped a lot, thanks! Before I put this as correct answer I wanted to ask if you could also give some insight for the example at hand (in the question): When both, metric and loss, are differentiable, why would I choose a third option as loss? I don't mean that in that in the context that every metric expresses something different. I rather mean: When I choose `mae` as metric because it expresses what I want, why not optimize `mae` as loss as well?

Comment: @Markus in that case nothing prevents you from optimizing mae as loss

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro actually the compatibility with output activation function should also be considered. For example, using cross entropy loss function with  sigmoid/softmax as output activation function works very well because it could smooth the gradient. You might check it out in the book Deep Learning Ch.6.2, by Ian Goodfellow, Yoshua Bengio, Aaron Courville. Or search it online.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very good question.

Knowing your modeling, you should use a convenience loss function to minimize to achieve your goals. 
But to evaluate your model, you will use metrics to report the quality of your generalization using some metrics.

For many reasons, the evaluation part might differ from the optimization criteria.

Giving you an example, in Generative Adversarial Networks, many papers suggest that a **mse** loss minimization leads to more fuzzy images although **mae** helps to get a more clear output. You might want to trace both of them in your evaluation to see how it really changes the things.

Another possible case is when you have a customized loss, but you still want to report the evaluation based on accuracy.

I can think of possible cases where you set the loss function in a way to converge faster, better and etc, but you might measure the quality of the model with some other metrics as well.

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 1):

I just asked myself that question when I came across a GAN Implementation that uses mae as loss. I already knew that some metrics are not differentiable and thought that mae is an ecample, albeit only at x=0. So is there simply an exception like just assume a slope of 0? That would make sense to me.

I also wanted to add that I learned to use mae instead of mae because a small error stays smaller when squared while bigger errors  increase on relative magnitude. So bigger are being penalized more with mse.